# 外部の質問サイトに誘導するような書きこみにどう対応すると良いですか？

Tags: 討議

とある書籍に関係する質問に対して、著者の方がご自身のもってらっしゃるその書籍専用の Q&A ページへ誘導する書き込みをなさっていました。

- https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/66302/19110
- https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/66301/19110

これは回答として投稿されています（信用度の関係で回答しかできないです）。回答にはなっていない内容なので何かしら対処がしたいです。しかしたとえば私のモデレーター権限でコメントに変換したとして、それは be nice な対応なのでしょうか。他にも削除などの選択肢もありますが、どれが良いのか悩みました。

というのも、以下のようにどのやり方も悩ましいものだったからです。

- コメントに変換　→　スタック・オーバーフローの質問の範囲に入ってそうなオントピックな内容の投稿に対して、外部サイトへ誘導するようなコメントは OK なのでしょうか？
- 削除　→　著者の方から反応があった、という情報を削除してしまうのは OK でしょうか？　また、この場合投稿者の方と何もコミュニケーション無しに削除するのは be nice でしょうか？
- そのまま何もしない　→　この回答に対して、どういった基準で投票すれば良いでしょうか？
- 別の方法　→　コメントでやり取りし、よい落としどころを見つけるのはひとつの策ですが、どういう方向に話を進めれば良いでしょうか？

私自身、オフトピックな投稿であれば Yahoo! 知恵袋など他の Q&A サイトに誘導した経験があります。しかしオントピックな場合の誘導は初めてです。どう対応すればより be nice な形にできるでしょうか。

Answer (score 9):

プロダクトオーナーが、サポートは自分の管理下のissue trackerで(のみ)行っていると表明しているのであれば、今回の質問に対してその情報を記載することは有用であるかと私は考えます。
ですので、削除すべきではない、というのが私の意見です。

ただ、質問に対する回答ではないので、記載されている選択肢の「コメントに変換」が妥当であると思います。

---

ちなみに、以降の理想的な流れのひとつとして私が想定しているシナリオは次のようなものです:

1. 質問者がGitHubのIssuesに書けば良いことに気づき、そちらにも記載[済]
2. プロダクトオーナーが回答、あるいは問題を解消
3. SO上の該当質問に対して、質問者が自己回答

---

＜余談＞
[vagrantのLinuxでminikubeを動かしたい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/66063/2808)
について、
「プロダクト固有の問題っぽいしGitHubのIssuesページも開いてるっぽいし、プロダクトオーナーと直接やりとりした方が低コストで問題解決できるだろうなあ。でも第三者が質問者に対してそっち行けと言うのも、プロダクトオーナーに対してこっち見に来いと言うのもちょっとヤな感じだよなあ…」
とか考えた末、結局[回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/66069/2808)と[プルリク](https://github.com/takara9/vagrant-minikube/pull/1#issue-409981078)で互いにリンクし「とどけっ…！この想い…！」と願うに留めていたのですが、それがかなったので個人的には満足しています
＜/余談＞

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます＆余談も参考になりました ;)　[自己回答](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3321/19110)の形で自分の考えもまとめてみて、やはり今回の場合はコメントへの変換が妥当そうなのでモデレーターとしてそのように行動します。「ちょっとヤな感じ」を穏当に処理なさっていただけたのがとても be nice だと感じています。ありがとうございました！

Answer (score 5):

yukihane さんの回答や YukiInoue さんにアドバイスを頂きつつ、質問者としては以下の考えにまとまりつつあります。

#### 取るべき行動

モデレーターに通報して回答をコメントに変換してもらう。

また状況に応じて、この Q&A にリンクしつつ、もし最終的に解決すれば質問者さんを含め関係者のどなたかが回答の形で投稿していただけると嬉しいという旨をコメントする（質問者さんの自己回答でも、著者の方の回答でも、第三者によるまとめでも OK）。

#### 行動の理由

スタック・オーバーフロ－は、世の中のプログラマーに役に立つ情報を蓄積することを目標としています。

まず、誘導したいという意思自体は問題ありません。スタック・オーバーフローは CC BY-SA のもと運営されているオープンな Q&A サイトであり、もちろんスタック・オーバーフロ－上で Q&A していただければ嬉しいのですが、今回のように著者の方の意向で、著者の方が管理されているサイト等で Q&A をやりたい場合そちらへの誘導を止める理由は特にありません。サイトに参加しない自由は常に存在します。特に今回の場合、GitHub の Issues という固有のライブラリに関する問題を一括管理できる場所で Q&A したいのは理解できますし、それをスタック・オーバーフローがブロックしてしまうのはプログラマーのためになっていなさそうです。

ただしその誘導が「質問の回答になっていない」ならば回答のまま残しておくのは好ましくありません。一方で著者の方が管理されている Q&A への誘導は質問に対して十分有益な補足情報となっているので、コメントとして残されているのは OK でしょう。逆に著者の方によるものでなければ、その誘導が十分有益な補足情報になっているかどうかを別個に判断すべきです（この点においては、投稿者ではなく投稿内容で判断していることに注意してください）。

このため、回答をコメントに変換してもらうのが良さそうです。